# How to change active class at each link click in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app, where in the _Layout.cshtml file I have something like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav pull-right navbar-nav">
        <li id="home" class="active"><a id="homeLink" href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'>Home</a></li>
        <li id="about"><a id="aboutLink" href='@Url.Action("About", "Home")'>About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href='@Url.Action("Services", "Home")'>Services</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href='@Url.Action("Contact", "Home")'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So the point is that when the website starts, the first link is set to active, then after each link click I want to set that one's class to active. I guess I need to write some jQuery code, but I cannot seem to figure out the answer.

**UPDATE:**

```
<ul class="nav pull-right navbar-nav">
    <li id="Home" class="active"><a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'>Home</a></li>
    <li id="About"><a href='@Url.Action("About", "Home")'>About Us</a></li>
    <li id="Services"><a href='@Url.Action("Services", "Home")'>Services</a></li>
    <li id="Blog"><a href=''>Blog</a></li>
    <li id="Contact"><a href='@Url.Action("Contact", "Home")'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**main.js**

```
$(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
        $('#' + '@ViewBag.Title').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Example views:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Services";
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}
```

Comment: you can't duplicate ID's

Comment: You don't have any IDs in your html code

Comment: Sorry, updated the code.

Comment: none of the click solutions will work if the page is not being loaded by ajax. Does clicking link load new page in browser? If so just match your controller to link in server code and add the class there

Comment: The pages are not loaded with AJAX I guess. That's why maybe the solutions below don't work for me.

Comment: The alternative is to have javascript parse the url and match the href in links by looking through them

Comment: @charlietfl Code example would be highly welcomed.

Comment: I don't work in MVC. Should be easy to google how to get current controller to match with and use some sort of `if` statement

Comment: @tett, Each of the answers do work (the class is added) - its just that except for the _Blog_ link, you immediately redirect to another page so you dont see it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It doesn't work. When I click the About link, still the Home link is highlighted.

Comment: @tett, It does, its just that the millisecond after the class is added, you then redirect to a new view (and that new view has the `.active` class applied to _Home_ link). The page you were on no longer exists. Change the code in my answer below to `$('a').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...})` to prove it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Indeed it seems to be working. But how can I solve the problem that I have?

Comment: @tett, Lots of possibilities. One might be to make use of the views `Title` property (assuming you use the typical `ViewBag.Title = "About";` in the view) - your could then use jquery to select the correct `li` tag based on this

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, I use the typical `ViewBag.Title` property. Can you give a code sample for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script will add the `active` class

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
  // uncomment the following line to prove it
  // e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
})
```

however, since your clicking on a link you don't even see it because you immediately redirect to another page using the same layout where the `active` class applied to the first `li` element (the new view has no knowledge of what you did on this page).

Since you seem to be wanting to highlight the `li` element relating to the current page, one option would be to give your `li` elements an `id` attribute matching the `ViewBag.Title` property and use that to apply the class.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav pull-right navbar-nav">
    <li id="home">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li id="about">@Html.ActionLink("About Us", "About", "Home")</li>
    <li id="services">@Html.ActionLink("Services", "Services", "Home")</li>
    ....
  </ul>
</div>
```

and the script

```
$('#' + '@ViewBag.Title').addClass('active');
```

Then in the `Index.cshtml` view,

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Home"; // or "About" for About.cshtml, "Services" for Services.cshtl etc.
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared_Layout.cshtml";  
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. Check my update in the original question please.

Comment: No, the script is only as I have shown (not inside the click event) - it just needs to run when the page is first loaded. And it can't be inside a separate `.js` file - Razor code is only parsed in the view, not in separate files

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you aren't doing anything to alter the way the links fire (loading content with ajax), you can compare the href of the links to the current url to figure out which one should be active.

```
$('.navbar-nav ul').children().each(function() {
  var link = $(this).find('a'); // or var link = $(this).children('a');
  if (link.attr('href') == location.href) {
    $(link).addClass('active');
    return false;
  }
});
```

All you'll need is to make sure the link href is formatted the same way it will appear in the url (relative vs absolute).